# can you run Java in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

Note: I'm new to this site, so if you downvote, **please comment why so I can edit it and avoid it in the future**

I know that you can use Java packages In JRuby, but is it possible to literally run Java in JRuby. For example, can you run Java inside a Ruby block similar to:

```
runJava() do 
    #Javacode
end
```

I did some research, but I only found how to run JRuby in Java.

Comment: The snippet provided is not a valid ruby code.

Comment: @mudasobwa I know, I was simply wondering _If_ there was a JRuby command that could run Java with a similar syntax.

Comment: You can use java packages from jruby, yes. No, you can't run java code inline like that (AFAIK)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok, thanks! Another question, why did everyone downvote? Did I break a rule? Or was my question just to dumb?   :)

Comment: @mocqoro: If I were to guess, it's because of [perceived] lack of prior research effort.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That might be True... Anyways, Thank you very much! If you post that as an answer I'll certainly like/aprove  :)

Comment: I just don't get it... I would be fine with people downvoting If they told me what was wrong and what I should edit... but just downvoting... Then I don't know what to avoid in the future...

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, the tooltip gives a couple of examples as to why one would downvote a question. Lack of research effort is one of them. You could have just copied that code in a Ruby file and run it to figure out whether it works or not, and the error message would have told you why it *cannot possibly* work. Then, there's the first paragraph, which has nothing to do with your question. (It should probably be a comment, or removed altogether.) Also, in at least one version of your question, you asked "how does JRuby work" which is a completely different (and much too …

Comment: … broad) question. In another version of the question, you first stated that you can use Java packages in JRuby, and then later asked whether you can use Java packages in JRuby … that doesn't make sense, if you already know you can do it, why do you ask if you can do it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanx, I'm new to stackoverflow and don't know all the shortcuts yet. What I ment with "can you run java in JRuby" was if ther was a module / gem that whould let you run java in JRuby. And, yres, "How does JRuby work" was WAY to broad of a question, that's why I removed it.  Yes, I know... The earlier version of this post was very bad explained... that's why I got a lot of downvotes. I wrote the questions way to fast and didn't read it through myself to catch some writing errors, I'm really sorry about that.  Thanks for your feedback, as I said... I'm really new to stackoverflow

Comment: ... and I know that this question was very bad... I'll try to do better in the future... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly [use java packages from JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby). This is, in fact, one of the main jruby's selling points (if not THE main).

And no, as far as I know, you can't run inline java code like that.

Comment: It sucks not being able to vote... I guess I'll have to wait in order to...

Comment: @mocqoro: no worries, you'll get there :)

Comment: Yeah... eventually... :)